# Parsing and removing parts of a string in perl

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I would like some help parsing a string of someones name. I would like to take the string and remove it so that only the first name will be in the string.

Suppose I have a name like this

```
Mr. John Doe
John Smith.
```

In both cases I would like to only get the first name of the string and delete all other characters.

---

**EDITED:**

So for both strings after they have been parsed will on have `John` in them

I was wondering if there was a way to do this problem with regex.

Comment: What happens when you have a strings like these...  "Smith John", "Joseph Joseph", or "Dr. James"?  Point being, in your question you didn't describe any parameters for the format of the input string or any rules you'd like to follow to get the output string.

Comment: The string will always have the first name and the last name along with some title such as "Mr.", "Mrs.", or "Dr."

Comment: "John Smith", in your example, does not have a title.

Comment: Remember that it's not possible to always get it right. "Ms. Mary Jane  Watson" and "Mr. Edward Van Halen" look the same but you can't tell the difference programmatically.

Comment: @Sparky, some names won't have a title and some will.

Comment: @Graeme the file that I am ready these names in from always have it in the format where there will only be two name; the first name and the last name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [split](http://p3rl.org/split) to place the parts of the name into an array.

Examine the first element to see if it's a title ("mr., mrs., dr., or miss").  If not, take it.  Otherwise, take the next element and stop.

**EDIT:  This is an answer to the OPs original question.**

**EDIT 2:** Please explain any down-votes.  As stated, the OP changed his question *after* I answered it.

Comment: Thats a good solution, but Its requires extra looping. I was wondering if there was a way to do this with regex

Comment: @Steffan Harris:  You did not say that in your original question!  And then you edited it without noting that extra requirement as an edit.

Comment: @Steffan Harris: This will be faster than regex! By a lot!

Comment: Why the down-votes?  The OP did not ask for a Regex solution in the original question... he added that later.

Answer (score 1):

This calls for using a module like [Lingua::EN::NameParse](http://p3rl.org/Lingua%3a%3aEN%3a%3aNameParse).  Really.